# Windows 10 Update Keeps Failing with Error 0x80070002

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I recently installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 Pro on my machine using the ISO from Microsoft's Media Creation Tool. I am now trying to bring the installation up to date, but the "2018-03 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for x64-based Systems (KB4088776)" installation keeps failing with error code `0x80070002`. Currently the machine is running build 16299.15. It's worth noting that if I look at my update history, I have an entry saying that this update installed successfully, but now it's failing again. Here's a screenshot to clarify:

[image: Windows 10 Update History]

Does anyone have any idea what is going on or know how I can fix it?

Comment: according to the catalog, 776 has been replaced (https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=2c72e703-9c4c-4146-9e32-cc4386b2cfb2).  Try downloading and installing this one manually: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4089848

Comment: Thank you for the link, but unfortunately it is not working. I tried installing "2018-03 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for x64-based Systems (KB4089848)" but I keep getting the error "The update is not applicable to your computer."

Comment: **0x80240034** indicates the download failed.  Have you performed a reboot, yesterday was March 29th, which means you installed it yesterday

Comment: Yes, I have restarted it many times, but it fails every time. Given that the update is listed as having been installed earlier in the history, is it possible that the update was installed, but for some reason it was never "registered" that it was installed?